# How to retrieve the insert statements from an SQL Database that I imported from an Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import, insert-statement

i recently used a MS excel database and imported it into an database but i want to get all the insert statements that the import made.

Is it possible? All i can see is the executed database in my object explorer but i want all the insert statements of the imported data??

OK let me try explain again :) i have thousands of rows of data in an excel spreadsheet, how do i convert the rows of data to a database.  I'm asking like this now because i think i just messed up on the previous try:(

Comment: that's not possible. once the sql is executed, the statements are essentially GONE. you can dump the database using MSSMS into a series of create/insert statements, if you want.

Comment: I haven't the foggiest clue as to what you're asking here.

Comment: Thanks Marc, how do i access that data that i imported into the object explorer? the rows of data?

Comment: Can you use SSMS to just do an import? Just right click the database and follow the wizard.

Comment: if someone would like to help me on my teamspeak server i would really appreciate it then i can talk and explain properly..:( ip:cogclan.no-ip.biz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the table in sql format
The Format of Output of .sql file is In the form
*Create Table Statements 

Insert each entry statement*
 So Open that .sql file and copy all INSERT statement

Hope this was your requirement

Comment: export from the excel? can it export to .sql?

Comment: You mentioned you have imported excel in database(MySql) So Export from MySql in .sql format

Comment: @AkashKumar the only thing I am clear on in this question is that it is **NOT** using MySQL. It using SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not getting this right:(  Yes i did use mssql import wizard to import the excel file. now i can see the database in my object explorer and i can query it for results, but im looking for the physical script that shows every row entered into the database so i can modify it. is it possible?

Comment: @Zane sorry that you don't understand its a weird question i know...  the import of the excel file went smooth but didn't give me what i wanted, the column names are messed up and want to change it or rewrite the database because the relationships are non existent. all i really wanted to import was the physical rows of data and drop it under my colums

Comment: Why not just Drop the table and re-import with the correct column names?

Comment: will try it , thanks alot for your help guys:) really appreciate it. Didn't know that an sql query is just a modification of the object database every time :$